# Cannot import 'PyPDF2' in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7, pypdf

I am wondering, why, for the life of me I cannot import and use `PyPDF2` (PDF library) in Python 3.7.

Firstly, my import fails at top of `main.py` (i.e. below)

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
```

Then I have tried `pip install PyPDF2` which lead to the below output:

```
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/pypdf2/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/pypdf2/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/pypdf2/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/pypdf2/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)'))': /simple/pypdf2/

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyPDF2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyPDF2
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this:**

```
pip install https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/1.23/
```

Comment: Nope; exact same error as above 'retrying retrying... etc'