# Why won't Python recognize that PyPDF2 is installed?

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm trying to import PyPDF2 and it won't work. I installed it using pip, then tried it with pip3, it is installed. When I try to import I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

I'm using Python 3.7. I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100089/cannot-import-pypdf2-in-python-3-7), doesn't seem any of the answers worked and I tried them myself to the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this problem try using sys.path to find the site-packages directory. I copied my PyPDF2 packages into my Python37 directory and now it works.

Comment: Consider using virtual environment

Comment: It's not for that big of a project otherwise I would.

Comment: Project size does not matter. Env separation does.

Comment: Would you mind explaining? I would appreciate the knowledge, I am still fresh on my programming journey.